# Saved file in Android is deleted after a restart

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to save some information in a file at the startup of an Android application and then check for if this file exists whenever I restart the application.

I am using:

```
using (Stream stream = OpenFileOutput("userinfo.xml", FileCreationMode.WorldWriteable))
{
   XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));
   xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, user);
}
```

To save the file, and:

```
Java.IO.File test = GetFileStreamPath("userinfo.xml");
if (test.Exists())
{
    //Do something
}
```

To check if the file exists.

This seems to work randomly. The check on file Exists() seems to work once after restarting but after restarting the application a few times more it does not work anymore, as if the file has been deleted for some reason

Comment: What language/framework is this?

Comment: Xamarin - Mono for Android

Comment: Could you please adapt the title/subject of your post? It will better attrackt the right people.

Comment: This problem is not Xamarin specific so I will leave it as it is

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes I'm using visual studio

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the file is actually there. Use the phone file browser to see if its there.

Also check if the required permission is in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: openFileOutput will be for internal/private memory. Other apps like file browsers have no access there. And external permissions are not needed for internal memory.

Comment: That's correct it's saved in the internal storage, and it's deleted when the application is deleted/updated. What are my options to have the information survive when the application is deleted/updated? Should I use the shared preferences?

Comment: Files saved tot the internal storage will always be deleted on removal of the application. The only way you can keep your file on the system is writing it tot the **external** storage as **public** file. Private files will be deleted on removal aswell.

Comment: To answer your question regarding shared preferences: shared preferences will be deleted on removal of the application.